# How to write image to catalog using imwrite OpenCV 3.1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have to write an image to subdirectory "pat" using OpenCV.
The subdirectory is located in project folder.
I tried:

```
imwrite("../../pat/Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
imwrite("../pat/Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
imwrite("/pat/Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
imwrite("\\pat\\Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
imwrite("//pat//Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
imwrite("\pat\Gray_Image.jpg", image_source);
```

I do not understand why i am wrong.

Comment: No error message ? Beware to the fact that the relative path is relative to the folder where your _shell_ is (the working directory) when starting your binary (probably different than where your _binary_ is). You could try to use an absolute path. The path should be written as usual on your OS.

Comment: Are you sure that the folder is in your working directory? Working directory is your project folder when you run your program from Visual Studio, but it will differ if you run it outside of the IDE - then it's the folder when the executable is located.

Comment: Yes, no error message. The program continues to run. The absolute path not works.

Comment: Yes, this folder in my working directory. I am write an image in my working directory.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to this folder? Is this folder already created? imwrite() won't create it for you.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OrYHFsL.jpg

Comment: I have permission to write to this folder.

Comment: Maybe it is a codec problem. Could you try changing the image extension to .png or .ppm or .pgm ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.
OpenCV using only full path.